# Failed Resolution of R$Drawable when using a bound Java Library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, java-binding

I am binding the java library [Material CalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview). With a set of 12 transforms in Metadata.xml I could bind the library with 0 errors and 15 warnings. I have added Support Library v4 Component ver 23.1.1 in the binding project as the jar file had a dependency on that. Also I have ensured that all the Resource assets are included in the jar file.

When I use this library in an Android Sample like below,

```
var materialCalendar= new MaterialCalendarView(this);
```

this exception gets thrown

```
Failed resolution of: Lcom/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/R$drawable;

Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:  Lcom/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/R$drawable; ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.R$drawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fingent.materialcalendarsample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fingent.materialcalendarsample-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
at java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.R$drawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fingent.materialcalendarsample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fingent.materialcalendarsample-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.setupChildren(MaterialCalendarView.java:358)
at at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.<init>(MaterialCalendarView.java:237)
at at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.<init>(MaterialCalendarView.java:216)
at at md56fd5622393123d59c6c51d78708f2ed2.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at at md56fd5622393123d59c6c51d78708f2ed2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
at Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.R$drawable
at at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
at ... 19 more
at Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00084] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1029
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance (IntPtr instance, IntPtr jclass, IntPtr constructorId, Android.Runtime.JValue* constructorParameters) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:306
at MaterialCalendarLibrary.MaterialCalendarView..ctor (Android.Content.Context p0) [0x000c5] in /Users/fingent/Projects/MaterialCalendarLibrary/MaterialCalendarLibrary/obj/Release/generated/src/MaterialCalendarLibrary.MaterialCalendarView.cs:505
at MaterialCalendarSample.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00009] in /Users/fingent/Documents/sreeraj/workspace/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView/MaterialCalendarSample/MainActivity.cs:17
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2475
 at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:0b8c341c-2f19-42d5-83e9-b3a815827e69 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
at java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/R$drawable;
at at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.setupChildren(MaterialCalendarView.java:358)
at at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.<init>(MaterialCalendarView.java:237)
at at com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView.<init>(MaterialCalendarView.java:216)
at at md56fd5622393123d59c6c51d78708f2ed2.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
at at md56fd5622393123d59c6c51d78708f2ed2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
at at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
at at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
at Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.R$drawable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fingent.materialcalendarsample-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fingent.materialcalendarsample-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at ... 18 more
at Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.R$drawable
at at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
at ... 19 more
at Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here is the link to the project in Github [Xamarin Material CalendarView](https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView)

Comment: My First intuition is that something is wrong with the input jar I am using. Not an expert with Eclipse and Java. Will need to find my way out. What is the recommended way to generate jar from source code ? I had used eclipse. There is also a command line method as described in this post http://www.wikihow.com/Create-JAR-File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about missing Resources that should be attached in Material CalendarView, you need an AAR file.

Just go Maven and get latest AAR file that published by Author: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/1.2.0

Remove the `material-calendarview.jar` and drag new file `material-calendarview-1.2.0.aar` on your binding project, done!

Comment: @trinnguyen,  I tried using the aar file. But still the same issue persists. Removed the jar file, added the aar file then cleaned the solution and rebuilt. Library builds successfully as earlier and when the bound library is used it throws the same exception again

Comment: @Sreeraj Check Build Action of arr file, should be: LibraryProjectZip

Comment: @Sreeraj Also remember to Rebuild the Xamarin.Android application project (Sample app), this is important point!

Comment: @trinnenguyen Yeah. BuildAction for aar is LibraryProjectZip and I tried cleaning and re-building both binding library project and sample project. But still the same issue.

Comment: @Sreeraj I'm not sure why you are still having that issue. Just invest little time on this: https://github.com/sreerajPR/Xamarin.MaterialCalendarView/pull/2/commits/fc7fc58d469ca2c1c13c2fb0eb8ac6e30dc90ca9

Comment: Hey @trinnguyen, It works now. Issue was resolved when it was changed to aar. I was referring the DLL of old project and din't realise even though the issue was fixed. Thank You buddy :-)

Answer (score 0):

A Drawable is a graphic resource and the Java exception is on the following line (from the lib your binding):

```
buttonPast.setImageResource(R.drawable.mcv_action_previous);
```

So you are missing `mcv_action_previous` which a PNG-based arrow located in the `res/drawable-xxxhdpi/mcv_action_previous.png` within the project that you are binding.

Are all the resources included? Any of your binding transformations or binding warning about resources?

Comment: I extracted the jar file with Archive Utility and checkd. mcv_action_previous.png file was present in res>drawable-xxxhdpi . res folder is located in the root folder. There are no warnings about resources while compiling.

Comment: @Sreeraj Either grab the prebuilt `.arr` since it includes the resources and Xamarin will automatically add those resources (it does not do that for `.jar`, only `.arr`. Or you will need to package them into the project yourself, consult the following link as Xamarin explains how to package those resources @ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

Comment: I tried using the prebuilt aar file. But the issue still persists.